# Change lat long starting point on tileLayer

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I'm working on a Leaflet map for a game. I'm trying to upgrade it to use tiles instead of an imageOverlay. On the imageOverlay map, I was able to get the lat long to place 0,0 in the center of the map. I have so far been unable to do the same with the tileLayer map. Currently the tileLayer map has 0,0 in the top left corner. The code (minus all the script, css and div lines) I use for the imageOverlay map is:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    crs: L.CRS.Simple,
    minZoom: -2,
    });

var bounds = L.latLngBounds([
    [-4000 /2, -4000 /2],
    [4000 /2, 4000 /2]
    ]);

var image = L.imageOverlay('data/biomeMap.png', bounds).addTo(map);
```

My code for the tileLayer is below.

```
var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [-128,128],
    zoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 4,
    crs: L.CRS.Simple
    });

 L.tileLayer('http://www.example.com/data/biomeMap/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```

Is there anything I can do to make the tileLayer map lat long function the same way as the imageOverlay map?

Comment: Wait a second, is this for KSP?

Comment: No it's not but I did get the idea from the KSP maps